# Getting stack overflows with a CUDA kernel

Tags: c, pointers, cuda, stack-overflow, parallel-processing

I have a huge problem with the code I am programming.
I am not an expert, and i asked many people before coming here. corrected a lot of things, too. So, I guess I am ready to show you the code and ask you my questions.
I will put the entire code here, as a  way to make you understand well what my problem is.
The thing i wanna do there is, if `ARRAY_SIZE` is too big for the THREAD_SIZE, so I put the data of the big array into a smaller array, specially-created with size `THREAD_SIZE`.
Then, I send it to the kernel and do whatever I have to do. But I am having problem on the part

```
isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
```

where the code stops, due to stack overflow. First, I made a double pointer of big_matrix. But people in the #cuda channel at freenode irc network told me it was too big for the CPU memory to handle it, that I should create a linear pointer. I did it, but I still have the same problem of stack overflow. So, here it goes... updated after some changes, that didnt work yet (the stack overflow stopped, but theres a linking and manifest update fail)

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 2048
#define THREAD_SIZE 32
#define PI 3.14


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
        int array_plus=0,x,y;
        float time;
        //unsigned int memsize=sizeof(float)*THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE;
        //bool array_rest;
        cudaEvent_t start,stop;
        float *d_isub_matrix;

    float *big_matrix = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
    float *big_matrix2 = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
    float *isub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];
    float *osub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];

        //if the array's size is not compatible with the thread's size, it won't work.

        //array_rest=(ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)/(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE);
        //isub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);
        //osub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);

        if(((ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)%(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)==0))
        {

            //allocating space in CPU memory and GPU memory for the big matrix and its sub matrixes
            //it has to be like this (lots of loops)



            //populating the big array
            for(x=0;x<ARRAY_SIZE;x++)
            {
                for(y=0;y<ARRAY_SIZE;y++)
                    big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y]=rand()%10000;
            }

            //kind of loop for the big array

            //Start counting the time of processing (everything)
            cudaEventCreate(&start);
            cudaEventCreate(&stop);

            cudaEventRecord(start,0);

            while(array_plus<ARRAY_SIZE)
            {

                //putting the big array's values into the sub-matrix

                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[(x+array_plus)*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
                }

                cudaMalloc((void**)&d_isub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
            cudaMalloc((void**)&osub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
            cudaMemcpy(d_isub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

                //call the cuda kernel

                twiddle_factor<<<1,256>>>(isub_matrix,osub_matrix);//<----

                cudaMemcpy(osub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

                array_plus=array_plus+THREAD_SIZE;
                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        big_matrix2[x*THREAD_SIZE+array_plus+y]=osub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y];
                }

                array_rest=array_plus+(ARRAY_SIZE);

                cudaFree(isub_matrix);
                cudaFree(osub_matrix);
                system("PAUSE");
            }

            //Stop the time

            cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,start,stop);

            //Free memory in GPU




            printf("The processing time took... %fms to finish",time);
                    system("PAUSE");

        }
        printf("The processing time took...NAO ENTROU!");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
}

//things to do: TRANSPOSITION!!!!
```

Another question is about the parallel part.
The compiler (Visual Studio) says that I engaged too many pow() and exp() at once.
How should I solve this problem?

```
if((xIndex<THREAD_SIZE)&&(yIndex<THREAD_SIZE))
    {
        block[xIndex][yIndex]=exp(sum_sin[xIndex][yIndex])+exp(sum_cos[xIndex][yIndex]);
    }
```

The original code is down here. I commented it because i wanted to know if at least my code was taking some value in the GPU. But it wasnt even launching the Kernel... so sad)

```
__global__ void twiddle_factor(float *isub_matrix, float *osub_matrix)
{
    __shared__ float block[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE];
    // int x,y,z;
    unsigned int xIndex = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = threadIdx.y;
    /*
    int sum_sines=0.0;
    int sum_cosines=0.0;
    float sum_sin[THREAD_SIZE],sum_cos[THREAD_SIZE];
    float angle=(2*PI)/THREAD_SIZE;

    //put into shared memory the FFT calculation (F(u))

    for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
        {
            for(z=0;z<THREAD_SIZE;z++)
            {
                sum_sines=sum_sin+sin(isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*z));
                sum_cosines=sum_cos+cos(isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*z));

            }
            sum_sin[x][y]=sum_sines/THREAD_SIZE;
            sum_cos[x][y]=sum_cosines/THREAD_SIZE;

        }
    }
    */

    if((xIndex<THREAD_SIZE)&&(yIndex<THREAD_SIZE))
        block[xIndex][yIndex]=pow(THREAD_SIZE,0.5);

        //block[xIndex][yIndex]=pow(exp(sum_sin[xIndex*THREAD_SIZE+yIndex])+exp(sum_cos[xIndex*THREAD_SIZE+yIndex]),0.5);

        __syncthreads();

    //transposition X x Y
    //transfer back the results into another sub-matrix that is allocated in CPU

    if((xIndex<THREAD_SIZE)&&(yIndex<THREAD_SIZE))
            osub_matrix[yIndex*THREAD_SIZE+xIndex]=block[xIndex][yIndex];



    __syncthreads();
}
```

Thanks for reading it all!

Below is the entire code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 2048
#define THREAD_SIZE 32
#define PI 3.14



__global__ void twiddle_factor(float *isub_matrix, float *osub_matrix)
{
    __shared__ float block[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE];
    int x,y,z;
    unsigned int xIndex = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = threadIdx.y;

    float sum_sines=0.0;
    //float expo_sums;
    float sum_cosines=0.0;
    float sum_sin[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE],sum_cos[THREAD_SIZE][THREAD_SIZE];
    float angle=(2*PI)/THREAD_SIZE;

    //put into shared memory the FFT calculation (F(u))

    for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
        {
            for(z=0;z<THREAD_SIZE;z++)
            {
                sum_sines=sum_sines+sin(isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*z));
                sum_cosines=sum_cosines+cos(isub_matrix[y*THREAD_SIZE+z]*(angle*z));

            }
            sum_sin[x][y]=sum_sines/THREAD_SIZE;
            sum_cos[x][y]=sum_cosines/THREAD_SIZE;

        }
    }


    if((xIndex<THREAD_SIZE)&&(yIndex<THREAD_SIZE))
    {
        block[xIndex][yIndex]=exp(sum_sin[xIndex][yIndex])+exp(sum_cos[xIndex][yIndex]);
    }




        __syncthreads();

    //transposition X x Y
    //transfer back the results into another sub-matrix that is allocated in CPU

    if((xIndex<THREAD_SIZE)&&(yIndex<THREAD_SIZE))
            osub_matrix[yIndex*THREAD_SIZE+xIndex]=block[xIndex][yIndex];



    __syncthreads();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
        int array_plus=0,x,y;
        float time;
        //unsigned int memsize=sizeof(float)*THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE;
        //bool array_rest;
        cudaEvent_t start,stop;
        float *d_isub_matrix,*d_osub_matrix;

        float *big_matrix = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
        float *big_matrix2 = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
        float *isub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];
        float *osub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];

        //if the array's size is not compatible with the thread's size, it won't work.

        //array_rest=(ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)/(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE);
        //isub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);
        //osub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);

        if(((ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)%(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)==0)&&(ARRAY_SIZE>=THREAD_SIZE))
        {

            //allocating space in CPU memory and GPU memory for the big matrix and its sub matrixes
            //it has to be like this (lots of loops)



            //populating the big array
            for(x=0;x<ARRAY_SIZE;x++)
            {
                for(y=0;y<ARRAY_SIZE;y++)
                    big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y]=rand()%10000;
            }

            //kind of loop for the big array

            //Start counting the time of processing (everything)
            cudaEventCreate(&start);
            cudaEventCreate(&stop);

            cudaEventRecord(start,0);

            while(array_plus<ARRAY_SIZE)
            {

                //putting the big array's values into the sub-matrix

                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
                }

                cudaMalloc((void**)&d_isub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
                cudaMalloc((void**)&d_osub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
                cudaMemcpy(d_isub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

                //call the cuda kernel

                twiddle_factor<<<1,256>>>(d_isub_matrix,d_osub_matrix);//<----

                cudaMemcpy(osub_matrix,d_osub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

                array_plus=array_plus+THREAD_SIZE;
                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        big_matrix2[x*THREAD_SIZE+array_plus+y]=osub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y];
                }


                cudaFree(isub_matrix);
                cudaFree(osub_matrix);
                cudaFree(d_osub_matrix);
                cudaFree(d_isub_matrix);
            }

            //Stop the time

            cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,start,stop);

            //Free memory in GPU
```

Comment: I don't see you are allocating memory for isub_matrix before copying the data from big_matrix to isub_matrix. Aren't you getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: Moreover, I don't see any cudaMemcpy from Host to device. you are allocating memory for isub_matrix but never copying any data into it.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: While I appreciate the humor, it is not a good idea to upvote questions based on a witty title.

Answer (score 3):

I see loads of problem in this code.

1. You are not allocating memory for isub_matrix before copying the data from big_matrix to isub_matrix

   ```
       for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
       {
           for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
               isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
       }
   ```
2. You are not doing any cudaMemcpy from host to device for isub_matrix. After allocating memory on the device for isub_matrix, you need to copy the data.
3. I see that inside the while loop you are computing the same data.

   ```
           //putting the big array's values into the sub-matrix

           for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
           {
               for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                   isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
           }
   ```

The for loop should be dependent on the array_plus.

I would suggest u to do this

```
for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
            {
                for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                    isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[(x+array_plus)*ARRAY_SIZE+y];
            }
```

1. moreover, I don't feel the use of array_rest. What is that used for?

---

Based on the updated version:

The error I see is

1. you are using osub_matrix as both host and device pointers. I would suggest you to create a another float pointer and use it for the device

> float *d_osub_matrix;
>
> cudaMalloc((void**)&d_osub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));

and call.

```
twiddle_factor<<<1,256>>>(d_isub_matrix,d_osub_matrix);
```

Then do

```
cudaMemcpy(osub_matrix,d_osub_matrix, ((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

1. By the way, it is not

   twiddle_factor<<<1,256>>>(isub_matrix,osub_matrix);

It should be

### twiddle_factor<<<1,256>>>(d_isub_matrix,osub_matrix);

**Final and completed code:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int array_plus=0,x,y;
        int array_plus_x, array_plus_y;
        float time;
        //unsigned int memsize=sizeof(float)*THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE;
        //bool array_rest;
        cudaEvent_t start,stop;
        float *d_isub_matrix,*d_osub_matrix;

        float *big_matrix = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
        float *big_matrix2 = new float[ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE];
        float *isub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];
        float *osub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE];

        //if the array's size is not compatible with the thread's size, it won't work.

        //array_rest=(ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)/(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE);
        //isub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);
        //osub_matrix=(float*) malloc(memsize);

        if(((ARRAY_SIZE*ARRAY_SIZE)%(THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)==0)&&(ARRAY_SIZE>=THREAD_SIZE))
        {

            //allocating space in CPU memory and GPU memory for the big matrix and its sub matrixes
            //it has to be like this (lots of loops)



            //populating the big array
            for(x=0;x<ARRAY_SIZE;x++)
            {
                for(y=0;y<ARRAY_SIZE;y++)
                    big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y]=rand()%10000;
            }

            //kind of loop for the big array

            //Start counting the time of processing (everything)
            cudaEventCreate(&start);
            cudaEventCreate(&stop);

            cudaEventRecord(start,0);
            for(array_plus_x = 0; array_plus_x < ARRAY_SIZE; array_plus_x += THREAD_SIZE)
            for(array_plus_y = 0; array_plus_y < ARRAY_SIZE; array_plus_y += THREAD_SIZE)
            {


                //putting the big array's values into the sub-matrix

                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[(x+array_plus_x)*ARRAY_SIZE+(y+array_plus_y)];
                }

                cudaMalloc((void**)&d_isub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
                cudaMalloc((void**)&d_osub_matrix,THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE*sizeof(float));
                cudaMemcpy(d_isub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

                //call the cuda kernel

                dim3 block(32,32);
                twiddle_factor<<<1,block>>>(d_isub_matrix,d_osub_matrix);//<----

                cudaMemcpy(osub_matrix,d_osub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

                for(x=0;x<THREAD_SIZE;x++)
                {
                    for(y=0;y<THREAD_SIZE;y++)
                        big_matrix2[(x+array_plus_x)*ARRAY_SIZE+(y+array_plus_y)]=osub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y];
                }

                cudaFree(d_osub_matrix);
                cudaFree(d_isub_matrix);
            }

            //Stop the time

            cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,start,stop);

            //Free memory in GPU
```

Comment: 1. well, i did it, then, using float *isub_matrix = new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE]; (same for the osub_matrix)

Comment: 2. i also created another variable to do what you suggested: cudaMemcpy(d_isub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

Comment: 3. ok, i did it :) thanks for the correction
1. (moreover...) its not really useful. I erased this part :P

Comment: now there are no stack overflow errors... but it has to link and "create the manifest", it fails. so are there more problems? :(

Comment: well, i updated the code... I tried to do what you said, but now i have, lets say... a different error o.O

Comment: I have updated the corrections. Can you tell me what are the errors that needs to be solved?

Comment: WOW! Vedaaaaa!!!! It workeeeeeeeeeed!!! I LOVE YOU, MAN (or woman)!!!!! :)))))))))))) I AM SO HAPPY! THANK YOU A LOT!

Comment: Welcome. Let me know if u have any other problem.

Comment: haha! well... it worked in a way... i had some problems with the final result! :(
It executes, it shows some results (all are 0.0000) and in the end, the compiler says an exception cudaError (memory state ox0000;...) and cudaError_enum (memory state 0x9903400x0025f7), but some times (not billions of times).
I guess it didnt work ALL, but its already a great step. :P
do u have any idea about this cuda Error? o.O
is it because of safe calls, or... i dont know, i never saw that before

Comment: If the result is all zeros, then it means something is wrong with the code. Can you post the complete code.

Comment: Why invoking the kernel with only <<<1,256>>>.

Comment: well, the strange this is that i got zeros for most of the cells, except for for the cells [1][0] until [1][9], that have some random numbers. (i updated the post with the complete code)
I invoke the kernel with only these numbers because my professor asked me to do so, that I could have one thread executing each cell. It was the "easiest" way to understand this programming model, as i couldnt understand much before (im an EXTREMELY newbie)

Comment: When I execute your code, I am getting some results, not all zeros. Moreover, I am not getting any cudaError (as you mentioned). Can you post the updated code.

Comment: well, this is the last update, actually. I updated that in the post (the last quote). So you are getting no exceptions? Have you tried to run all the 2048x2048 numbers? Because if you run just maybe 20 times, its ok. But if you printf all the cells, so at least in my case I saw a lot of exceptions of cudaError. i will run it in another computer (im using laptop) and see if theres a different thing.

Comment: by the way, Veda, do you know why I get some kind of overuse of the functions pow() and exp() in the kernel, if i try to take off the comments there?

Comment: one thing I do see is that                                          cudaFree(isub_matrix);
cudaFree(osub_matrix);  both are not needed because isub_matrix and osub_matrix are not the memory allocated on the device.

Comment: another thing is, it is not isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y];... It should be isub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]=big_matrix[(x+array_plus)*ARRAY_SIZE+y];

Comment: mmm interesting. I erased these cudaFree that u said, and there are no more cudaErrors in the compiler. At least. But the most "interesting" is that doesnt matter how many times i execute it, the results between the cells [1][0] and [1][9] are the same. There is something wrong that i cant figure it out, as the numbers are supposed to be chosen in a random order. Do you have any idea?

Comment: ooops! well i thought i already had done that! well.. i executed it again, with both things you told me to correct, but... still... the zeros between that cells... they persist on being there. Its so weird.

Comment: One thing I do noticed is that your code works only for the 1st iteration in the while loop. After that it is not working. One thing I would suggest you is that, try the code for smaller array_size and instead of going for random values for big_matrix, use 1 for all the elements of the big_matrix. By this way, you will know what the result should be. Let me know if you try it..

Comment: Another question is that, is it correct to have this statement " array_plus=array_plus+THREAD_SIZE;" before copying the result into the big_matrix2. I feel like it should be after copying the result into the big_matrix2. Moreover, I feel something is wrong in copying the data into the bi_matrix2. Check that as well.

Comment: well. I tried to do something like what you said. I erased the while part and put 1 to every cell of big_matrix. Then i put a printf on the time I was inserting the "1" to each cell of big_matrix. Guess what: ALL ZERO! Seriously, i have no idea what is going on. Because the algorithm is correct (2 loops, and then big_matrix[x*ARRAY_SIZE+y]...) any idea?

Comment: Hey first tell me what is the algorithm is about. What is the question that your professor wanted you to do. can you explain it first. I am trying to understand the code you have written.

Comment: ok. the code is about FFT. In this case (if you take off the comments), the kernel is the computation of a DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform), made by myself. So, this is a hierarchical algorithm, where I should compute just the size of the shared memory. So its kind of showing many small matrix of FFT together. Were I clear?
Then, now, I tried the printf() of the big_matrix (the first one, that receives the number 1 or rand()) and its printing just 0. No idea of what is wrong... :(

Comment: oh ok, I think you are using 2 dimensional block. but while calling you are using one-dimensional.

Comment: well, i guess I made them all just one dimensional, right?(new float[THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE]).. and i think im calling just one dimensional, or not?

Comment: one important question is why the big_matrix is not producing random numbers, as it should be. another question is why, at the bottom, big_matrix2 is producing zeros. this is extremely strange. o.O

Comment: do u mean to say that the rand() function didn't work.. Did you have the required header file. The big_matrix2 is all zeros because you are not computing all the parts of the bi_matrix. How can I explain to you. Lets say for example, the array_size 64 and thread_size is 32. then it means you are dividing the big_matrix into 4 parts and trying to compute. But you are not computing all the 4 parts.. do you understand..

Comment: about the rand, it doesnt work.I tried also putting just the value "1", and it gives me something else than the value i inserted.About the big_matrix2, i got what you mean (i hope so! hehe). I changed the line to big_matrix2[(x+array_plus)*THREAD_SIZE+y]=osub_matrix[x*THREAD_SIZE+y]; It worked... now it doesnt show zeros. hehe thanks for the explanation.I guess theres some evil force in the part that populates the big_matrix! o.O

Comment: So finally did it work... have all your problems are solved. Except the rand function. may be you might be missing some header files.

Comment: ah! Plus... do you know something about the overload of the pow() and exp()?if i put like block[xIndex][yIndex]=pow(exp(sum_sin[xIndex][yIndex])+exp(sum_cos[xIndex][yIndex]),0.5); it says that "more than one instance of overloaded function "pow" matches the argument list"
how can i overcome it? ㅠㅠ

Comment: wow! cool! thanks a lot, veda! you are awesome! i couldnt understand fully the reason of the overload (because of the language version of compiler and windows), thanks once more for all this help! seriously! you are almost guiding a blind person! im very grateful for you! :)

Comment: dear veda, thanks for everything but i found an error. Theres something really weird with the kernel call... seems like its not calling the kernel, although everything runs (including cudaMalloc, when i paste one matrix to another and try to print the second one). But when i call the kernel and try to put the number "1" or any other thing, when i copy it back to the cpu, it show NOTHING. Its like nothing happened in the kernel (or, worse, it didnt call the kernel). What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the line.

```
 cudaMemcpy(osub_matrix,isub_matrix,((THREAD_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE)*sizeof(float)),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

This is because you allocate both `osub_matrix` and `isub_matrix` in the device.